# Cluster initializers with ARC

Tags: objective-c, class-cluster

Parsing through this [document on class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4), `NSNumber` implements `initWithChar:` in roughly the following manner:

```
- (id)initWithChar:(char)c
{
    [self release];
    return [[__NSCharNumber alloc] initWithChar:c];
}
```

Similarly, you could use this pattern for initializing views from a Nib:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    id realSelf = [[self class] nib] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil][0];
    realSelf.frame = frame;
    [self release];
    return realSelf;
}
```

I'm wondering, does ARC manage the releasing of the unreturned `self` in these cases?  Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: That's "class clusters", not "cluster classes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the details [in the clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init).

`init` implicitly uses the `__attribute__((ns_consumes_self))` attribute, meaning that while `self` is defined as `__strong id self`, the initial assignment does not perform a retain.  This means as soon as `self` is reassigned or the function terminates, `self` will be released using standard strong rules.

To get an +1 out, there is an implicit `__attribute((ns_returns_retained))` which prevents the returned object from being released at the end.

At a high level, ARC plans to release the initial value of `self` one extra time by the end of the function, while also retaining the return value, maintaining its +1 output.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Could you please show, how the code would look like?

Comment: @Slabko There's nothing to it really other than returning a new instance of a subclass in `initWith...`.  I've put together a couple examples of class clusters here: https://github.com/bnickel/Cluster-Initializer-Examples

Answer (score 3):

It would fall under standard ARC object ownership rules, whereby the "unreturned `self`" would end up without any strong references and would therefore be automatically released for you when it falls out of scope.